# Best way to handle re-rendering a view in backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I have the following view:

```
Main.Views.Login = EventQ.View.extend({
events: {
    "submit form": "login"
},

template: "login",

login: function(e) {
    var me = this;

    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/users/login",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: $(e.currentTarget).serializeArray(),

        success: function(data, status){
            EventQ.app.router.navigate('dashboard', true);
        },

        error: function(xhr, status, e) {
            var result = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
            me.render_with_errors(result.errors);
        }
    });

    return false;
},

render: function(done) {
    var me = this;

    // Fetch the template, render it to the View element and call done.
    EventQ.fetchTemplate(me.template, function(tmpl) {
        me.el.innerHTML = tmpl(me.model.toJSON());
        done(me.el);
    });
},

render_with_errors: function(errors) {
    var me = this;

    // Fetch the template, render it to the View element and call done.
    EventQ.fetchTemplate(this.template, function(tmpl) {
            me.el.innerHTML = tmpl(errors);
    });
}
});
```

and a simple template like this:

```
<form>
<input name="username" />
<input name="password" />
<button type="submit" />
</form>
```

what I'm  looking to do is be able to re-render the template if errors are returned but keep the input's populated.  An error template would like like:

```
<form>
<input name="username" />
<label class="error">required</label>
<input name="password" />
<button type="submit" />
</form>
```

Is there a way to bind the view to a model or something that I can check?  Right now the render_with_errors works except for the fact that I lose all the data filled out on the form.

Comment: Have you considered not using a separate template for the error? Maybe in your real situation, the templates are more different. But in your example, you could just show/hide the error message in your error/success handlers.  Or even with some on-the-fly validation.

Answer (score 1):

It's common for people to get in the mode where they only way they think that the only way they can change the page is a full re-render of a template.  But rendering templates are only 1 solution to updating the page.  You are still free to use traditional methods from within your backbone view.  So another possible solution is for you to simply adjust the dom from your view.

So make your template be the following:

```
<form>
<input name="username" />
<label class="error" style="display:none">required</label>
<input name="password" />
<button type="submit" />
</form>
```

And then make the following change in your login function:

```
error: function(xhr, status, e) {
    var result = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
    me.showLoginError();
}
showLoginError: function() {
    this.$('.error').show();
}
```

And of course you can always add more to that, message customizations, etc.

It's just important to remember that full template renders aren't the only way for your backbone code to react to changes in the application state, and it's ok to manipulate the DOM in a method other than render.

Answer (score 0):

Supposed you have a Model like this:

```
Main.Models.LoginModel = EventQ.Model.extend({
    /* ... */
    defaults: {
        'username': "",
        'password': ""
    },
    /* ... */
```

When your Ajax-Request successes, you can navigate to the next page.
If it fails, you can set your model to use undefined to indicate a missing value:

```
// assumed you did not enter your password
this.me.model.set( { 'username': textBoxValueSoFar, 'password': undefined });
```

Then can built up an template like this (it will be the same as on first page load):

```
<form>
    <input name="username" value="{{username}}" />
    {{#unless username}}
    <label class="error">required</label>
    {{/unless}}
    <input name="password" value="{{password}}" />
    {{#unless password}}
    <label class="error">required</label>
    {{/unless}}
</form>
```

{{unless}} checks if, the value is not false, undefined, null or []. So on first page load, it is an empty string and no error message is provided.

See http://handlebarsjs.com/ the part with "unless" for more details.

So what you do is: you use an empty string to indicate that no wrong value has been entered so far. You use undefined to check if a wrong value (in fact, nothing) has been entered.
In your template you can check for this an act appropriately.

Comment: How do you make the template to update itself when the model changes?  Otherwise you are stuck with re-rendering the template.